# Writing in a font file

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I need to create a method that given the file name and an integer n writes to a character file with that name, n random integers, one per line.
This is my code, I think it is written correctly but the file I pass remains "empty" with size 0 bytes. Can someone help me?

```
   public static void scriviIntero(String nomeFile, int n) {
    try (PrintWriter scrivi = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(nomeFile, true))) {
    Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int nuovo = random.nextInt(99999);
            scrivi.println(nuovo);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Errore di I/O nella funzione scriviIntero nel tentativo di scrivere sul file " + nomeFile);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This should work. You need to check if `n>0` and make sure you're looking at the file you're writing to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is incorrect initialization of `FileWriter`. Check this out where I put `true`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    appendRandomNumbersToFile("e:/foo.txt", 10);
    appendRandomNumbersToFile("e:/foo.txt", 20);
}

public static void appendRandomNumbersToFile(String fileName, int n) throws IOException {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("n should be positive");

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true))) {
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            writer.println(random.nextInt());
    }
}
```

***P.S.** This is from JavaDoc:*

```
public FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) {}
public PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush) {}
```

Comment: Why would this matter? The way op has it, it is non-appending and auto-flushing.  Where you are making it append.